# Unable to import compiled java avro files into Scala codebase

Tags: java, scala, gradle, build.gradle, avro

I am trying to reference the generated Avro files in my scala code basebase. I am using the commercehub avro gradle plugin to generate the avro java compiled files and they get correctly generated in `build/generated-main-avro-java/`

This is how my gradle file looks. The problem is that the java files get generated correctly but I cannot import them in my scala code. Any idea on what I maybe doing wrong here?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.lightbend.akka.grpc:akka-grpc-gradle-plugin:0.7.2"
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.8'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'application'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.8"
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.9.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.lightbend.akka.grpc.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"

akkaGrpc {
    language = "Scala"
    generateClient = true
    generateServer = true
}

mainClassName = 'com.test.App'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.daemonServer = true
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.fork = true
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useCompileDaemon = false
}

def scalaVersion = "2.12"
ext.elasticAPMVersion = "1.14.0"

// Define a separate configuration for managing the dependency on Jetty ALPN agent.
configurations {
    alpnagent
}

dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.2"
}

test {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:" + configurations.alpnagent.asPath
    maxParallelForks = 1
}

run {
    mainClassName = mainClassName
    standardInput = System.in
}

task runServer(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = mainClassName
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:" + configurations.alpnagent.asPath
}

shadowJar {
    classifier = 'shadow'
    mainClassName = mainClassName
    archiveName = "${title}-${version}.jar"
    append 'reference.conf'
    destinationDir new File("./docker/bin")
    zip64 true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, you need to add the generated sources folder to source sets and scala compiler source - something like this:

```
compileScala {
    source = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java', 'build/generated-main-avro-java/']
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        avro {
            scala.srcDir file('build/generated-main-avro-java/')
        }
    }
}
```